# How to extend django admin user model with new fields?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to add more fields to django built in admin user model. How can I achieve it?

Actually , There are three users on django server, student , teacher and parent. And by adding a 'role' field to user model, I can identify which type of user is log-ged in . So how can I extend the model field.

I'm expecting to identify different role of users in login.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model